# toggle class on click Vue3

Tags: vue.js, templates, vite

I want to toggle a class on click, but something does not work here.

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

let isOpen = ref(false);

const openMenu = () => {
  isOpen = !isOpen;
  console.log(isOpen);
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_burger" @click="openMenu">
      <span :class="isOpen ? 'top-line' : '' "></span>
      <span :class="isOpen ? 'bottom-line' : '' "></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What did I do wrong? `isOpen` is actually changed by the click, but not the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isOpen` is a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), so you have to unwrap it with `.value`:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
let isOpen = ref(false);

// isOpen = !isOpen; ❌
isOpen.value = !isOpen.value; ✅
</script>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-vlygce?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Alternatively, you could use the [Reactivity Transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactivity-transform) to avoid having to unwrap:

```html
<script setup>
//import { ref } from 'vue';
//let isOpen = ref(false);
let isOpen = $ref(false); ✅

isOpen = !isOpen;
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-s3cqyp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_burger" @click="openMenu">
      <span :class="isOpen ? 'top-line' : '' "></span>
      <span :class="isOpen ? 'bottom-line' : '' "></span>
   </div>
 </div>  <-----
</template>
```

You're missing that end tag. Could it be that?

Comment: nope, this was my mistake, sorry.